# Sony Add-On SDK for Android 4.2.2+?

Tags: android, add-on, sony

Just upgraded my Xperia Z to Android Jelly Bean 4.2.2 :

I am curious to know if there is already Sony SDK support for Android 4.2.2 (API17) or 4.3 (API18) or if support is limited to 4.1.2 (API16) with which the Xperia was shipped?

Basically, I'm doing a bit of dev through eclipse and I only see the SDK entry in API16. Now that I've upgraded I'm worrying I'll see problems.

**Question :**
So, in Android SDK, can I enter Sony SDK in API17/API18 or will I need to simply wait for Sony to update the SDK?

(I have had a look, I just don't know if Sony are slow at this or if I'm missing something in the process; Sony SDK instructions are only for API16 and the entry only appears in API16 in Android SDK manager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current Sony Add-on SDK only supports API level 16 as you have noted.  You will need to wait for an update if you want to use any new features of API 17 or 18.  What kind of problems are you worried about?  Your phone should still be backwards compatible with previous API levels so as long as you set android:targetSdkVersion="16" in your AndroidManifest.xml your app should run without issues.

Comment: Between Unity -> Eclipse -> phone, updating caused mega breakages. I was worried for a while! I re-imported all my projects and nothing. I had to switch platforms on all my projects and switch them back to Android before they started working again and, heck, was I relieved! Your answer is as I suspected. Sony being slow. Thanks for the reply.